# Check if Pandas Series is of type string

Tags: python, pandas

I import some data from a parquet file into a DataFrame and want to check the data types. One of the data types I expect is strings. To do this, I have something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
col = pd.Series([None, 'b', 'c', None, 'e'])
assert((col.dtype == object) and (isinstance(col[0], str)))
```

But, as you can see, this does not work if I accidentally have a `None` value at the beginning.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that efficiently (preferably without having to check each element of the series)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html) to retrieve and check the first non-NA item:

```
isinstance(col.iloc[col.first_valid_index()], str)
```

Answer (score 2):

As of [Pandas 1.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html) there's a [`StringDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype), which you can use to check if the `pd.Series` contains *only* either `NaN` or string values:

```
try:
    col.astype('string')
except ValueError as e:
    raise e
```

If you try with a column containing an `int`:

```
col = pd.Series([None, 2, 'c', None, 'e'])

try:
    col.astype('string')
except ValueError as e:
    raise e
```

You'd get a `ValueError`:

> ValueError: StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA

Comment: I like that solution, but since my Series is quite long, I'd go with the spot-check proposed by @Stef

Comment: That depends on the purpose. If you have an object dtype and want to ensure the entire column contains no numerical data I'd go with this one. If that is not necessary the stef's appraoch should do @raphael

Answer (score 0):

you can convert entire `series` all values to `str` type as follows:

```
col = col.astype(str)
```

`None` value will became string value.