# Select all columns containing scalar values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

Is there a way to select all `str`, `float` and `int` columns in a dataframe, excluding columns holding objects like dicts and class instances? `df.select_dtypes(include=[int, float, str])` raises `TypeError` due to `str` and `df.select_dtypes(include=[int, float, object])` doesn't distinguish between strings and other objects.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()

df["E"] = df.A.map(lambda x: {"E": x**2})

df.dtypes

df.select_dtypes(include=object)
>>>     C   E
0   foo1    {'E': 0.0}
1   foo2    {'E': 1.0}
2   foo3    {'E': 4.0}
3   foo4    {'E': 9.0}
4   foo5    {'E': 16.0}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62391886/2823755

Comment: [Checking if a data series is strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191832/checking-if-a-data-series-is-strings),